# Ionic 4: Set default ionic ion-select option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Struggling to set the default option in an `<ion-select>` control. Using v4 rc2 but this has been an issue since I started with the late v4 betas.

The `<ion-select>` correctly sets the default selection but I get the small down caret. The selected option is not displayed. When I select the control, the alert is displayed and the correct option is selected. Or am I doing something wrong?

Does the order of setting the `measureSetId` vs loading the `measureSets[]` matter?

Thoughts? appreciate any help on this.

```
<ion-select name="measureSetSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedMeasureSetId">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let measureSet of measureSets" [value]="measureSet.measureSetId">
    {{measureSet.name}}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

public measureSets: IMeasureSet[];
public selectedMeasureSetId: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.measureSetsApiService.query().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedMeasureSetId = result.find(i => i.isDefault).measureSetId || 1;
      this.measureSets = result;
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to officially be a bug. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17225

Comment: I can confirm that this has now been fixed in Ionic 4.0.2

Answer (score 2):

When the `options` list contains objects, you need to use `[ngValue]` and `[compareWith]`
Try this code:

```
<ion-select name="measureSetSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedMeasureSet" [compareWith]="compareById">
  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let measureSet of measureSets" [ngValue]="measureSet">
    {{measureSet.name}}
  </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In your Component:

```
compareById(o1, o2) {
    return o1.id === o2.id
  }
```

Update to component part to set the ngModel to object:

```
public selectedMeasureSet: IMeasureSet;

ngOnInit() {
  this.measureSetsApiService.query().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedMeasureSet = result.find(i => i.isDefault) || result.find(i => i.id === 1);
      this.measureSets = result;
    });
}
```

Also consider referring this document for further reading on it: https://medium.com/@kastepanyan24/how-to-set-selected-option-dynamically-in-angular-6-85c99958cca5

Comment: Looks like a likely solution but I think these are broken in the RC for ionic v4. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14598

Comment: I added `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to my page module. This now builds but the default value still fails to show. You stated "when you use objects"... is there any way to do this without objects? I think I have another `ion-select-option` that is only using an array of string and it suffers from the same issue. Are you sure there isn't a bug with the ionic component?

Comment: Hi - Sorry for the delay, I think the reason default is not working is that the `ngModel` was being set to `id` and `option` value, i.e `ngValue` was being set to object. I changed the part of the component to use the `IMeasureSet` object as `ngModel` on the `select`. Hope this works.

Comment: I gave your latest a try without other refactoring and while it builds, nothing is selected even with the modal pops. Are you using Ionic v4? From what I can find, my original code worked just fine in v3 and this is definitely a v4 issue. I added some info to an existing, open issue in github including a possible workaround: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15716

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the time and suggestions. I seem to know more about ionic than angular. Fairly new to both.

Comment: `Error: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select-option'.`